# Query ImportRange with date and location

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language, google-sheets-query

I currently have a file with a bunch of columns with Date in `column 1` and location in `column 3`.  I wanted to pull a specific number based on the date and location. Currently, it just keeps pulling the column header based on the `query`. Attached is the google sheet with Sheet2 pulling the data.  Based on the formula, I would like it to return `0.72` in cell `B2 Sheet2`.

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1Xd0qi9lBuhIwwWAvD7qxkubXPAdo9D0jVC5hkmdd8zA","Sheet1!A:D"),"select Col4 where Col1='"&$A2&"' and Col3='"&B$1&"'")
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Xd0qi9lBuhIwwWAvD7qxkubXPAdo9D0jVC5hkmdd8zA/edit#gid=505310051

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used an alternative method using INDEX/MATCH to get the lookup of the value.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(IMPORTRANGE("1Xd0qi9lBuhIwwWAvD7qxkubXPAdo9D0jVC5hkmdd8zA","Sheet1!D:D"),match(1,(IMPORTRANGE("1Xd0qi9lBuhIwwWAvD7qxkubXPAdo9D0jVC5hkmdd8zA","Sheet1!A:A")=A2)*(IMPORTRANGE("1Xd0qi9lBuhIwwWAvD7qxkubXPAdo9D0jVC5hkmdd8zA","Sheet1!C:C")=B1),0)))
```